Setting from UNLOGGED to LOGGED takes a long time
I am trying to load data with pictures stored in a BLOB column. Each picture is around 1MB in size. I have about 200K rows.
First try, I copy the table straight away. After about an hour, it stops and copy only around 900 records.
Second try, I turn off the LOG by issuing "ALTER TABLE skema1.bnp__attach2 SET UNLOGGED;". Then I copy the data. After about 4 hours, it is a success. But... when I try to count using COUNT(*), it is not finished in 5 minutes. I terminate the process before its complete. Then I try to return the LOG using "ALTER TABLE skema1.bnp__attach2 SET LOGGED;" Its been 15 minutes and still going on.
How long does it normally takes ? Am I doing the right thing ?
Thanks

It's not clear WHY you started setting the table UNLOGGED and then back to LOGGED. I would stop fiddling until you know what the machine it is on is doing. Get some stats for cpu/disk/network load before doing anything else. Also check what queries are still running and maybe check the locks after that.

I set it to UNLOGGED because I want to load some bulk data faster. When on LOG mode, it fails. Anyway, it takes 90 minutes to finish the setting to LOG. then I run reindex which takes about 35 minutes..

If the final table is to be LOGGED, then don't toggle logging: it is unlikely to improve the total time required to get to the final state. The post lacks sufficient infromation to assess expected performance or to identify the root cause of performance issues. Please update the post with table DDL (including indexes), the code used to copy the table, the excution environment, and actual table statistics such as storage size and average row size. Unless the code is the problem, this post would be better suited to DBA Stack Exchange.

Hi @RichardHuxton, i am setting the table to UNLOGGED in order to make the loading process faster... In reality, its not that much faster but the loading process is successfull compared to when the table was in LOG mode
